# Thin plate stiffness: analytical formula to validate FEM model

Tags: finite-element

I tried to compute analitically the stiffness of a cantilever thin plate (shown in picture). The plate is also homogeneous and isotropic. The aim is to compare the result I obtain with the result I get when running the FEM analysis.

[image: plate]

$a = 0.127; b = 0.0508; h = 0.0012; E = 7*10^{10}; \nu = 0.3$

This is my theoretical derivation:

$D \nabla^4 w(x,y,t) + \rho h \ddot{w}(x,y,t) = 0$

where $w$ is the coordinate in the $z$ direction and $D = \dfrac{E h^3}{12(1-\nu^2)}$ is the flexural rigidity, $\rho$ is the density and $h$ the thickness.

$w(x,y,t) = \vec{N}(x,y) \vec{u}(t)$ approximation with a trial set

I am interested in the first bending mode only, therefore the trial set $\vec{N}(x,y)$ has only one element:

$N_i(x,y) = X_r(x)Y_s(y) = X_1(x)Y_1(y)$

The boundary conditions $\vec{N}(x,y)$ has to satisfy are

$w(0,y) = 0$ constraint on the translation

$w_{/x}(0,y) = 0$ constraint on the rotation ($_{/x}$ means derivation with respect to $x$)

Therefore $X_1(x) = \biggl(\dfrac{x}{a} \biggr)^2$ and $Y_1(y) = \biggl(\dfrac{y}{b} \biggr)^0 = 1$

The stiffnes $K$ can be found solving:

$K = \int\int_{A} D [N_{/xx}(N_{/xx}+\nu N_{/yy})+N_{/yy}(\nu N_{/xx}+N_{/yy})+2 (1-\nu)N_{/xy}N_{/xy}]dA $

The only terms different from $0$ are $N_{/x}$ and $N_{/xx}$. After the integration on the area $A$ of the plate I obtain

$K = \dfrac{4Db}{a^3} = 1098.8$

Then I run the FEM analysis and I post-process the results: knowing the time history of the acceleration and the input force applied to the plate ($p = \sin(\omega t)$ applied at the bottom tip corner of the plate, $\omega = 1^{st}$ natural frequency of the plate) I can compute:

$f_i(x,\dot{x}) = p_i-m\ddot{x}_i$

Then I can extract the curve $f(x)$ setting $\dot{x} = 0$. Fitting this curve with a line and computing the slope of this line I get $K = 3618.0$ which is different from the analytical value.

What am I missing/doing wrong?